# Change MongoMapper current database at runtime

Tags: ruby, runtime, mongomapper

How to change the current MongoMapper database at runtime?

Also, is there a way of mapping a model to a database whose name is dynamically calculated? For instance:

```
class MyEntity
    include MongoMapper::Document
    set_database_name "#{some_dynamic_value}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a specific database for a model, do...

```
class MyEntity
  include MongoMapper::Document
  set_database_name "entities_database_development"
end
```

You can do do string interpolation there, but that's only resolved when the class is loaded and then never again.

To calculate a database name every single time a database is needed, override either the class or instance database method.

```
class MyEntity
  include MongoMapper::Document
  def database
    connection.db("my_database_#{rand}_development")
  end
end
```

See the [persistence plugin source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/master/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/persistence.rb) to get an idea of the kind of damage you can do by overriding.

Comment: Excelent. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first part of your question, just do:

```
MongoMapper.database = 'dbname'
```

Comment: I don't even need to create a new connection? Simply calling the accessor= will change the database for me?

Comment: Correct. MongoMapper will use the existing connection.